# TreeView.MouseRightButtonUp Event Triggering SelectedItemChanged issue XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, dependency-properties

I have a custom treeview helper that is firing off iCommands and I was wondering if someone could take a look at my code and help me identity the issue.

```
private static void PreviewMouseRightButtonDownChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dpe)
    {
        if (!(obj is TreeView))
            return;

        var view = obj as TreeView;

        view.SelectedItemChanged += (sender, e) => SetSelectedItem(view, e.NewValue);
        view.MouseRightButtonUp += (sender, e) => SetSelectedItem(view, e.Source );

        var command = (ICommand)(view as DependencyObject).GetValue(PreviewMouseRightButtonDownProperty);
        if (command != null)
        {
            if (command.CanExecute(null))
                command.Execute(new DependencyPropertyEventArgs(dpe));
        }
    }
```

My issue is that I want to pass in e.NewValue to SetSelectedItem when the event MouseRightButtonUp is triggered. In the function above you can see that it is passing the 'view' and 'e.Source'. I do not wish for it to pass e.Source rather I want it to pass over e.NewValue.

Comment: the SelectedItemChanged Event takes in 2 parameters *(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)* while the MouseRightButtonUp event takes in *(object, MouseButtonEventArgs)*
MouseButtonEventArgs does not hold a value for NewValue like RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs does.  I am looking for a way to extract that NewValue variable and pass it in to SetSelectedItem from MouseRightButtonUp.

This isn't an error question this is a logic question

Comment: The SetSelectedItem only passes in true or false on individual items. Which i have implemented already. But its not the solution im looking for. This solution is bulky.